# Taking notes when programming?

Tags: c

I just got my first programming book, and I just started programming.
I have a little question. Should I take notes while reading the book, or should I just memorize, and refer back if I forget something?

Thanks

Comment: Try both and see what works for you.

Comment: Write Code. Then write some more code. And after that, write more code. Blindly memorizing is foolish. Practicing is wise.

Comment: "I've started cooking my first meal, should I put in some cayenne pepper?" I have no clue if you're making soup or baking cake, man.

Comment: Take notes, highlight, write in the margins.  You'll probably never refer back to them, but the act of doing so helps you focus on important points.

Comment: Would you take notes to your notebook? So you could refer later to your notebook instead of your printed book?

Comment: Jonathon is right, start coding (and commenting in your code)...you'll continue to build up a set of tools to refer back to and improve...lawyers don't memorize every case, they work in a room full of references...don't memorize, just learn to ask the right questions of the right sources

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] before too long, in part so you understand why the question is not really on-topic for Stack Overflow.  If you'd asked it back in the days of the Wild West (late 2008), you'd have been fine.  Things have gotten a bit stricter since then.

Answer (score 5):

1. Never read from just 1 book, read multiple books on the subject to get a better picture.

   - for C read The C Programming Language, How To Program - C, C: A complete reference and then C a reference manual(by Harbison and Steele) touching on at least C99
2. Take notes, keep a book handy at all times - think before you ink though.
3. Always sit by a computer + text editor + compiler (yes, do not use an IDE - learn with manual compilation)
4. Learn good debugging techniques, `gdb` is fine to start off with(although has a significant learning curve)
5. Be attentive to what is being said in the books and - also do not forget to experiment all the time. Programming is best learnt by doing it/practicing it.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer! I still have a few questions to the comment you left, since I'm completely new at programming. 1. What does this mean? touching on at least C99 2. What does this mean? gdb is fine to start off with(although has a significant learning curve) That is the questions I have to ask now :-) And thank you for helping!

Comment: @OliverMichaelsen C99 is a standard for 'C' language. Any good book of today should teach you both C89(another standard for 'C') and C99. GDB is a debugger, from GNU - if you are completely new at programming I suggest you pick up a `modern` C book first, maybe "C How to Program" is good to begin with.

Comment: I have "The C Programming Language" right now, and I will get all the books you listed above, and also download the C how to program. I have a last question for you, I'm not born as a mother tongue for English, I'm Danish, do you think I will understand it though? I mean all the hard words, do you think a non English person can understand it good even though he isn't English? Last words, Thank you so much for helping me, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @OliverMichaelsen I am a non-native english speaker myself. I am Indian and my mothertongue is Marathi(the local language of Bombay(mumbai)). I can understand the books thoroughly - why not you ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much, what can you program? I'm living in Singapore, I go to an international school, I'm currently 16, and I plan on making programming a living someday, because I love thinking about being able to make software yourself. I get good grades in English, and my grammar and vocabulary is also decent, so I hope for the best! :-) Thank you for helping me, it is really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to understand what is being said to you by the book, I've tried memorizing before.. it doesn't work I would suggest a bit of both, but mostly understanding it that way you would know what you are coding also practice your level of confidence of coding will increase and you'll continue to want to code more.